# How do I reduce guessability of MongoDB ObjectIDs?

Tags: mongodb, security, brute-force, objectid

[MongoDB ObjectIDs are guessable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577450/are-mongodb-ids-guessable)

I'm running an application that has publicly available resources located at

`http://application.com/resource/**ObjectID**`

These resources need to be publicly accessible (not behind a login), however I'm trying to reduce the chance of a hacker brute-forcing ObjectIDs and scraping them at will.

My idea is to include a randomly generated key with each MongoDB document, so that it can be matched up when the request is made. For example:

`http://application.com/resource/**ObjectID**/**Key**`
`http://application.com/resource/**ObjectID**?key=**Key**`

or even

`http://**Key**.application.com/resource/**ObjectID**`

If the key doesn't match the one stored in the document, then the server will return 404.

**I realize this isn't true protection in the sense of guaranteed privacy, because if someone in the middle is sniffing URLs, they can access the resource.** I'm just trying to prevent someone from brute-forcing ObjectIDs.

Is this approach feasible and effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of the original answer you referenced on ObjectID generation, guessable is qualified by "given enough time".

Rather than focusing on whether your IDs might be guessable by brute force, I would look at approaches to detect and mitigate any brute force attacks. This removes the aspect of giving an adversary enough time to try all possible combinations (an approach that could work regardless of your ID format).

For example, obvious signatures to detect brute force attacks might include:

- a large number of 404 requests from a specific IP address
- successive requests for incremental ObjectIDs (which should be rare)
- invalid ObjectIDs (if the adversary is unaware of the expected format)

There are many different strategies and countermeasures to consider, but a helpful starting point would be OWASP's info on [Blocking Brute Force Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks).

> These resources need to be publicly accessible (not behind a login), however I'm trying to reduce the chance of a hacker brute-forcing ObjectIDs and scraping them at will.

If the resources are public, there may be an easier way for an adversary to find them: crawling public pages and fetching the linked resources. In this case, you could still apply anti-crawling strategies but these become trickier if you want to avoid affecting legitimate users. For example, a large number of valid requests from a specific IP might indicate a corporate or ISP proxy rather than someone trying to abuse your service. Smart crawlers can also mimic user patterns (delay between requests, randomness in requested urls, ..) in order to try to defeat any protections.

As a starting point see: [Anti-crawling Techniques](http://www.slideshare.net/ayman2nov/anti-anti-crawling-techniques).

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is hard to see your goal here. Resources should be publicly accessible and at the same time you are worried that some one can guess the location of the resource. It might be better if you will include the reason why guessing ObjectIDs in your application will cause a problem.

I assume that that you are trying to do some sharing service which allows to exchange data (like dropbox via file sharing) and you basically trying to protect data behind the ObjectID.

There is no problem with the way you outlined in such a case, so I will just add another approach: create your own objectIDs (some randomly generated long strings). One potential problem is that they can collide, but this event will be really rare so if you will wrap it into try catch and redo on fail, you should be ok.